# Different number of observations when using SampleRegions

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, sentinel-1, training, scatterplot

I have a code in GEE which creates two images from sentinel-1 (SAR) and from sentinel-2 (NDVI) , creates from them paired image and then creates scatter plot from the two bands in the image. In order to create the scatterplot, I know I need to run kind of training and i'm a bit confused about it and about my results.

This is the code I have that seemed to be working:

```
// make an image for the two variables
var pairedImage =  ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([imageNDVIcor,SARreproject]).toBands().rename(["NDVI","SAR"]);
print("pairedImage",pairedImage);
// Generate a sample of points within the region
var sample = pairedImage.sampleRegions(geometry, null, 150);
print("sample",sample);
// Generate chart from sample
var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(sample, 'NDVI', 'SAR')
    .setChartType('ScatterChart');
print("chart",chart);
```

The point is that I get results that look nice but I can't understand, for example: 
this is suppose to be my point? what is this? what are those values?

var sample = pairedImage.sampleRegions(geometry, null, 500);

[image]

and this is with:
var sample = pairedImage.sampleRegions(geometry, null, 150);:

[image]

and this is when it's 1000:
[image]

How come using less points lead to more ponts in the correlation? I feel confused and i'm afraid that I don't understand something very basic with the sample points.

My end goal is to understand why I have gotten those two different charts when 500 has lesspoints than 100  and 1000 had the least. what'shapenning here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the `sampleRegions()` function:

```
sampleRegions(collection, properties, scale, projection, tileScale, geometries)
```

You're changing the third argument - scale. Increasing the scale will decrease the number of pixels you can sample, which in turn decreases the number of samples.

Comment: To add to this, if you don’t specify a scale it will sample at the scale of the top image layer (beware of memory allocations).

Comment: so what does scale refers to in this case?

Comment: From the docs:
"A nominal scale in meters of the projection to sample in. If unspecified,the scale of the image's first band is used."

Comment: @Daniel maybe it's problem of language as English is not my mother tongue, but from what is written I have understood that the scale is kind of pixel size? and no way it was used to this test right?

Comment: Pixel size - that's pretty much it. On having fewer sampled pixels with larger scale: Think of the extreme case, where your scale is so big, that your image only contains a single pixel. Then you couldn't get more than one single sample, since you only have one pixel to sample from.

Comment: For more on scale and how it can affect results, see the [Scale](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/scale) docs.

Comment: so then, how do I know what is the correct sccale to use for my image if my goal is to calculate correlation in the end?